# Can I bypass OpenVPN for a website address rather than IP?

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn

Recent political events (the snoopers carter) have prompted me to start looking at this again. I want to use a VPN for the vast majority of my traffic BUT I also want to be able to use Netflix which very effectivly detects and blocks any VPN connection

What I want to do is use my VPN for everything except those sites who don't allow VPN connections.

I have been directed to this site previously

http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/configuring-static-routes-in-debian-or-red-hat-linux-systems.html

Which is fine for small sites, but the issue is, this involves knowing the IP address, and Netflix distribute the server load, so I need to know 1000s of IPs and there's no complete list of them. The IPs is constantly changing too so I can't just add each IP as I encounter it. So, is there anyway I can direct OpenVPN to ignore any connections to a specific site?

Comment: Not all that possible, routing occurs lower in the OSI model.  There is a switch available with openvpn that will pull the fqdn on connect and then add the route, however when you DNS the host it's unlikely that the IP will be the same.  Look up --allow-pull-fqdn